# c# SpeechSynthesizer SpeakCompleted return variable

Tags: c#, speechsynthesizer

Hoping someone can help! :)

What I'm trying to achieve is have the reader_Speak() method return true when it's finished speaking. Similar to WaitUntilDone of the old SpeechLib.

Here is the code I have :-

```
    public void reader_Speak(string strSpeech)
    {
        reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        reader.SpeakAsync(strSpeech);
        reader.SpeakCompleted += new EventHandler<SpeakCompletedEventArgs>(reader_SpeakCompleted);
    }

    private void reader_SpeakCompleted(object sender, SpeakCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        reader.Dispose();
    }
```

Here is what I want :-

```
    public bool reader_Speak(string strSpeech)
    {
        reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        reader.SpeakAsync(strSpeech);
        reader.waituntildone();
        return true;
    }
```

Anyone any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: You had to set speak compleated event before you called speak async.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using SpeakAsync and a completed callback, simply use the `Speak` method which is blocking.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Asti. I'm not entirely sure what exactly you suggest. I've changed the SpeakAsync to Speak and been playing around with it a little but it still doesn't do what I need. So far the program listens for a speech recognition input and then feeds the string to speechlib for a tts output. I want to pause the listener object until the speaker has finished otherwise it just creates a loop saying the same word over and over again.

Comment: private void Reco_Event(int StreamNumber, object StreamPosition, SpeechRecognitionType RecognitionType, ISpeechRecoResult Result)
        {
            objReco.Pause();

            string strSpeech = Result.PhraseInfo.GetText(0, -1, true);
            textBox2.Text = strSpeech;

            SpeechSynthesizer reader;
            reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            reader.SelectVoice("Acapela Telecom HQ TTS English (US) (Heather 22 kHz)");
            reader.Speak(strSpeech);

            objReco.Resume();
        }